# IIS 8.5 and Tomcat, rewrite conditions does not work

Tags: iis-8

I am facing problem with IIS rewrite module. I googled it and search too much but didn't find a solution till now.
I have IIS 8.5 on Windows server 2012 R2. The website is running on Tomcat v7. The ISAP extension and URL Rewrite module are installed on Web Server.
I would like to block few admin pages on my website for public domain while it should be accessible from internal network through hostname/IP of the server.

Admin pages with public domain are : http://my.website.com/abc/jsp/login.jsp, http://my.website.com/xyz/admin.jssp

My web.config rewrite section is -

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="AdminAccess" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(login.jsp|admin.jssp)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="my.website.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

The above does not work. If I remove the {REQUEST_URI} from condition, then it works but block all the pages. I tried multiple combination but nothing worked till now. Can you advice how to achieve this in IIS. I tried implementing similar rewrite in Apache and those worked.

Comment: I believe apache rules that are working can be converted into url rewrite rules.

Comment: You might try `<match url="(login.jsp|admin.jssp)$ />", instead of using such an condition.

Comment: @Lex Li, thanks for the suggestions. I tried this as well but it didn't help either.